# Subset and bijection implies cardinal equality?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I hope I have not hereby created a duplicate, please perdon me if I did, but I had this question for a while now:

> Let $A \& B $ be two sets such that $A   \subseteq B$. Suppose there exist a one to one (bijective) function $f : A \to B $. Then have we got $|A|   = |B|$?

I know that if these sets are finite, it works, but what about the infinite case

Thank you

T. D

Comment: What you've written is false, but if you change $A=B$ to $|A|=|B|$, it is true. It is also true for the infinite case by the definition of cardinality.

Comment: That is what I meant,

Comment: It's always true that if there is a bijection $A \to B$ then $|A| = |B|$, regardless of whether $A$ is a subset of $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A = 2\mathbb{Z}$ (ie the even integers) and $B = \mathbb{Z}$. Then, $A \subseteq B$, and there is a bijection between them, (namely $f:B \to A$ defined by $f(x) = 2x$) but the sets are not equal

Comment: I did a mistake see the corrected

Comment: Well, by definition of cardinality, if there exists a bijection between the sets, then they have the same cardinality.